# ASP.Net Login Control Attempted Login Log VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, authentication

I am using the asp.net login control with sql server integration.  I don't see any references anywhere to being able to log the logins and disabling logins if too many bad passwords are attempted.

Is there a VB codebehind event that can be triggered if it's a bad username/password combo?  Basically I had the idea of creating a table that logs the ip and time and whether or not the login was successful.  From there I can disable the login control if a certain number of failed logins occur within a timeframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link to the events that the login control exposes.  There's a really good explanation for each of them:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9x0hd040.aspx

Hint: LoginError event to log failures

MaxInvalidAttempts is set in the membership provider configuration: MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.aspx

Comment: Thank you, the LoginError and OnLoggedIn are exactly what I needed.  Now I can create my own rules and logging info.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **maxInvalidPasswordAttempts** attribute when configuring your SqlMembershipProvider in the web.config:

```
<membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider"
      userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
      <providers>
        <add 
          name="SqlProvider" 
          type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
          connectionStringName="SqlServices"
          applicationName="MyApplication"
          enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
          enablePasswordReset="true"
          requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
          requiresUniqueEmail="false"
          passwordFormat="Hashed"
          maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
          passwordAttemptWindow="10" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
```